# Facebook Graph API - #4 error - application request limit reached

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to get the number of likes from a Facebook page with the following line of code in JavaScript, but I get the "application request limit reached error" even though I only made one API call to a single FB page

```
var jsonData = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://graph.facebook.com/" + name);
```

> Request failed for https://graph.facebook.com/nba returned code 403.
>   Truncated server response: {"error":{"message":"(#4) Application
>   request limit reached","type":"OAuthException","code":4}} (use
>   muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

I'm confused on why this is happening and I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow regarding this problem, but none seemed to give the right solution or point me in the right direction. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: How often do you do the request? And add an access token to the request

Comment: Hmmm how would I know how often I do the request? Isn't it only when I reload the page that it makes another request? Also, why would I need an access token? I'm not using Facebook login

Comment: You have to create an Application in Facebook's Developer Console and obtain the API key. Use the API key to obtain access token, then use the access token in the request. Read the official documentation for full tutorial.

Comment: You should use an access token because the rate limit is higher if you do.

Comment: For those who have just come here from Googling this error: **Stack Overflow is a programming website, we are not Facebook's forum. If you have concerns about this issue, please ask it over on the [Facebook Help Community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community) instead.**

Answer (score 0):

#### App Level Rate Limiting

This rate limiting is applied globally on application level. When the app uses more than allowed resources the error is thrown.

Recommendations:

- Do not make multiple calls in small amount of time, spread out the calls throughout the day.
- Do smart fetching of data, you can always fetch important data only, you can remove duplicate data as well
- Use parameters: "since", "until", "limit" to limit/filter the requests

[You can find out more in Official documentation here!](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/api-rate-limiting)